# How to handle `PartialRender` Models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, user-controls, viewmodel

if by any means I happen to have

```
public class DoorsModel
{
    public DoorsModel() { }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    public String DoorLayout { get; set; }
    public bool ReplicateSettings { get; set; }
    public List<DoorDesignModel> Doors { get; set; }
}

public class DoorDesignModel
{
    public DoorDesignModel() { }

    public HttpPostedFileBase FrontFile { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase BorderFile { get; set; }
}
```

and in my `View` I have a normal form to populate the Model Properties but the `List<DoorDesignModel>` I'm using a User Control and use

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("DoorDesign", Model.Doors); %>
```

inside `DoorDesign.ascx` I have:

```
<%@ Control 
       Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
       Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<MyProject.Backend.Models.DoorDesignModel>>" %>
```

to display all form I have a `for` clause

```
MyProject.Backend.Models.DoorDesignModel field;
for (i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { 
    field = Model[i];
    ... 
}
```

and I'm using the HTML

```
<input type="file" value="Upload file" 
    name="Doors.FrontFile[<%: i %>]" id="Doors.FrontFile[<%: i %>]">
```

but soon I press the submit button, my model returns a `null` List :(
and I'm creating and setting a new list when starting the View as

```
public ActionResult Doors()
{
    DoorsModel model = new DoorsModel();

    model.Doors = new List<DoorDesignModel>();
    for (int i= 1; i<= 24; i++) // Add 24 Doors
        model.Doors.Add(new DoorDesignModel());

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Doors(DoorsModel model)
{
    // model.Doors is always null !!!

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        ViewData["General-post"] = "Valid";
    else
        ViewData["General-post"] = "NOT Valid";

    return View(model);
}
```

What do I need to have in order to return the Doors List from the `RenderPartial` part?

a simple mockup of the View

[image]

Comment: 1. Have you created a DoorsModel Model
    Binder?
 2. Do you have the From enctype set to "multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: @Bivoauc 1. Yes, you can see it as an Inherit my Model in the User Control - 2. Yes, I do and works great with the `Image` outside the User Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same problem. Found this website: http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx

Essentially it is all about 
`<input type="file" value="Upload file" name="Doors[<%: i %>].FrontFile" id="Doors[<%: i %>].FrontFile">`

Comment: exactly, I ended up doing like that :)