# How to bind POST data with a model that contains multiple models (ie: a model containing multiple custom objects)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a parent View that uses a few partial views. Each partial view has its own custom model.
The parent View is a model containing each of the partial view's model. In other words this parent View model is NOT flat.

How do i get POST data to bind with the parent's model object? Do i have to write a custom model binder?

**Update**
I'm not binding to a collection of objects of the same type (ie: a collection of uploaded files). I'm binding to object that contains multiple of objects. For example:

```
   public class ProductViewModel { 
        public ProductTreeViewModel TreeView; 
        public ProductDetails Details; 
        public ProductBreadcrumb BreadCrumb; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: [How to handle `PartialRender` Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080845/how-to-handle-partialrender-models)

Essentially it is all about

```
<input type="text" name="Doors[<%: i %>].FrontFile" id="Doors[<%: i %>].FrontFile">
```

Does that help?