# ASP.NET MVC 2.0: Making the POST Action receive my Model's sub-models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I'm trying to reuse some existing Models (and especially the Load/Save functions associated with them), so I've aggregated them into the current Model:

```
public class EditModel {
    public SubModel1 {get; set; }
    public SubModel2 {get; set; }
    /* ID and some text fields */
}
```

The problem is, after I fill the form and hit submit, in the Action associated with POST these sub-models all have default/empty content.

```
/// POST for Edit
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditCommunity(EditCommunityModel model) {
        if (bad stuff happened)
            return Json("Failure");
        //model.SubModel1 is != null, but all fields are empty.
        // ID and the aforementioned text fields come correctly.
        Save(model.ID, model.SubModel1, model.SubModel2);
        return Json("Succeeded");
    }
```

I've done this reuse before without problems, when using an .aspx for the Edit equivalent, and would therefore call a GET Action to properly construct the Model. But now I'm restricted to an ascx, because I'm trying to edit in a modal dialog (if there's a way to load an aspx in a div, then this problem is over; but it occurs to me this would be contrary to what an aspx is intended for.)

This is, in short, what I'm trying to do; I'll also add two strategies I've tried to apply, both of which have the same effect: empty sub-models.

**First try** used an AJAX call to populate Edit.ascx.
In `Edit.ascx`, the wrapper for edit dialog was included in Manage.aspx, and the EditModel was passed without any initialization

```
    <div id="editDialog" style="display: none;">
         <% Html.RenderPartial("Edit", new EditModel()); %>
    </div>
```

In the grid, a cell would be marked as edit, and on click would call the following javascript function:

```
    function onSelectRowEdit_Click(id) {
        if (id) {
            //Get data from selected row
            var ret = jQuery("#table_grid").getRowData(id);
            //Show Edit modal control
            var actionUrl = '<%= Url.Action("EditInfo", "Manage") %>';
            var data = "externalId=" + ret.OrgId + '&Id=' + ret.Id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: actionUrl,
                data: data,
                error: AjaxError,
                success: ShowEdit
            });
     }
 }
```

`EditInfo(string, string)` would create and return a JsonResult, which was then received by ShowEdit; showEdit would fill Edit.ascx and use jQuery to present the div as a dialog:

```
    function ShowRes(ret) {
        $("#form_Edit").validate();
        jQuery("#editDialog").dialog('destroy');
        Init_EditDialog();

        /* $('#...').val(ret...);, many times over */

        //Show Dialog
        $("#editCommunityDialog_Content").show();
        $("#editCommunityDialog").dialog('open');
    }
```

**Second try** attempted to bypass `new EditModel()`, and to use a View returned by a Controller. It did achieve exactly what the first try did, with significantly less code, but had the same issue on Submit.

```
 <div id="editDialog" style="display: none;"></div>
 <!-- ... -->
 function onSelectRowEdit_Click(id) {
        if (id) {
            //Get data from selected row
            var ret = jQuery("#table_communities").getRowData(id);
            //Show Edit community modal control
            var actionUrl2 = '<%= Url.Action("ShowEdit", "Manage",
                new { CommunityId="_COMMID_", ExternalId="_ORGID_" }) %>';
            editImg = editImg.replace("_COMMID_", ret.Id);
            editImg = editImg.replace("_ORGID_", ret.OrgID);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: actionUrl2,
                data: data,
                error: AjaxError,
                success: ShowRes
            });
        }
    }
```

ShowEdit was rewritten to return `View("Edit", model)`, and ShowRes would simply write the result to the div's html.

```
    function ShowRes(ret) {
        //...
        $("#editDialog_Content").html(ret);
        //Show Dialog
    }
```

Needless to say, the form in `Edit.ascx` has fields like `<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubModel1.EditProfile)%>` so that's not where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out my answer in this question to see if that helps: [How to handle `PartialRender` Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080845/how-to-handle-partialrender-models/)

Comment: This article and its dependants were all very interesting; unfortunately, it doesn't apply to my situation: my equivalent to Index(Basket) is `ShowEdit(string communityId, string externalId)`; ModelState only contains those two values, so there's nothing to clear (moreover, they are constants for Edit.ascx purposes, so they're actually useful). But it did point me to an interesting fact: in `EditCommunity(EditCommunityModel model)`, ModelState contains only Id and non-sub-model fields; there's nothing along the lines of `ModelState["SubModel1_EditProfile"]`